# Making django html form perform 2 actions on submit

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm working on a django web app, and there's an html form which I need to do 2 things when the form is submitted: create a record in the app's database and post some of the values collected to another website (e.g. a payment site).

The problem I'm having is getting the form to do the 2 things simultaneously. I know an HTML form can only have one action, and I've read some posts here on StackOverflow about using javascript to get the form to execute 2 or more actions, but everything I've tried so far hasn't worked for this situation. They all seem to get only one action to work.

This is what my django template looks like right now:

```
{% extends "some other template" %}
{% block content %}
<div>
...
<form id=form1" name="trans_form" method="POST" >
...
<!--DATA TO POST TO PAYMENT SITE-->
<input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="some value" />
<input type="hidden" name="transaction_amount" value="some value"/>
<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="some value" />
<input type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="some value" />
<!--DATA TO POST TO PAYMENT SITE-->
...
<!--DATA TO POST TO APP DATABASE-->
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.id }}">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="CC">
<input type="hidden" name="ref_no" value="{{ ref_no }}">
Amount: <input type="text" name="amount" id="id_amount" required />
Ref ##: <span>{{ ref_no }}</span>
Date: <span>{{ cur_date|date:'d/m/Y' }}</span>
<a href="#" id="pay-btn" class="button" onclick="submitForm();">Submit</a>
<!--DATA TO POST TO APP DATABASE-->
...
</form>
...
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
<script>
function submitForm()
{
    createRecord(document.forms["trans_form"]);
    sendToPay(document.forms["trans_form"]);
}
function sendToPay(f)
{
    f.action= "www.paymentsite.com";
    f.target = null;
    f.onsubmit = null;
    f.submit();
}
function createRecord(f)
{
    f.action = "url to view that creates the record in database";
    f.target = "_blank";
    f.onsubmit = null;
    f.submit();
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

What do you think? Am I trying to achieve the impossible? If not, point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: `f.action = ` should probably include `https://` before the `www` for your `sendToPay` function.

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply POST to the payment site from your controller:

```
def handle_payment(request):
    post_to_payment_site(request)
    write_payment_info_to_db(request)

def post_to_payment_site(request):
    data = {'transaction_id': request.form['transaction_id',
        # etc.
    }

    requests.post('payment-provider-url', data=data)
```

If you *cannot* accept POST data intended for your payment provider then you can do one of the following things:

- Send your payment provider an XHR request - this requires that your payment provider properly implement CORS for the endpoint you are posting to.  When that request completes, you can submit the form normally.
- Change the `target` attribute of your form to point at an `iframe` or a new tab / window.  Then, when the `iframe` loads, remove the `target` attribute, switch the `action` back to your endpoint and submit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was able to configure the write_payment_info_to_db function and that works fine. However, setting up the post_to_payment_site function as you suggested results in a Type Error "QueryDict object is not callable". I used "request.POST('payment-provider-url', data=data)" in the last line, and this is where the exception location for the error is.

Comment: @debodunmcg - that's `requests`, not `request` ;-)  I was assuming that you had access to the [third-party Requests library](docs.python-requests.org).  You could use `urllib` too, it would just take a few more lines of code. Sorry, I should have made that clear!

Comment: No problem, @Sean. I don't have access to the payment-site's request library, but I have a solution that works. I made an HTML page that stands like a middleman between my form and the payment site. So, on submitting the form, the record is created in my app's database, relevant data needed by the payment site are sent to the middleman HTML page, and it submits the data to the payment site on load. The beauty of this is the user never gets to see the middleman. Probably not the best solution because it requires one extra hop, but it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my problem. I'm not sure it is the most efficient solution, but here it is.

I made one more HTML page to act as a middleman between my app and the payment site. It's a very simple page, practically a replica of the first form page but with only the required fields to be posted to the payment site. This way, there's no need for much JavaScript. Submitting the form creates a record in the app database, sends the needed data to the "middleman", which then posts the data to the payment site. The user never actually sees the middleman throughout the process.

Like I said, this might not be the most efficient solution, but it works fine.

First, here's the code for the views.py:

```
def write_payment_info_to_db(request):
dt = datetime.now()
form = Form()
err = False
if request.method == 'POST':
    #Collect data to send to GTPay
    transaction_id      = request.POST['transaction_id']
    transaction_amount  = request.POST['transaction_amount']
    customer_id         = request.POST['customer_id']
    customer_name       = request.POST['customer_name']
    #Create record in db for "valid" form data
    form = Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return render_to_response('middleman.html', {'transaction_id': transaction_id,
                                                    'transaction_amount': transaction_amount,
                                                    'customer_id': customer_id,
                                                    'customer_name': customer_name},
                                    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        err = form.errors
        return ...
else:
    return ...
```

And here's the middleman:

```
<html>
<body onload="document.submit2paymentsite_form.submit()">
    <form name="submit2paymentsite_form" action="payment-provider-url" target="_self" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="transaction_id" value="{{ transaction_id }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="transaction_amount" value="{{ transaction_amount }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="{{ customer_id }}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="customer_name" value="{{ customer_name }}" />
    </form>
</body>
```